# Strange property in a class

Tags: c#

Could you describe what it does? I met it in one of projects and don't know how it works.

```
public object this[int i]
{
    get { return columnValues[i]; }
}
```

Comment: [Indexed Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Also see [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **indexer**, used for indexing, for instance we use it for getting character from string.  You can ready about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx),

```
string str = "heel";

char chr = str[0];
```

This is how indexer could be made for classes

```
class Sentence
{
    string[] words = "The quick brown fox".Split();
    public string this [int wordNum] // indexer
    {
       get { return words [wordNum]; }
       set { words [wordNum] = value; }
    }
}

Sentence s = new Sentence();
Console.WriteLine (s[3]); // fox
s[3] = "kangaroo";
Console.WriteLine (s[3]); // kangaroo
```

Answer (score 3):

That is called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). It allows you to use the square brackets on your own type.

Comment: +1 for the totally irrelevant positive side effect of indexers. =)